# Phrase suggester collate query in java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The PhraseSuggestionBuilder in elasticsearch java API has a collateQuery method that takes a String as input. but there is a problem, this code:

```
collateQuery("\"match\": {\"title.phrase\" : \"{{suggestion}}\"}")
```

will result in something like this:

```
"collate" : {
"query" : "\"match\": {\"title\" : \"{{suggeston}}\"}"
}
```

as you see the escaped quotes are still there and I get "failed to derive xcontent" error. I can not find an example of collateQuery using java api. what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem in the Java API by building the collate query with the conventional QueryBuilder, such as:

```
MatchQueryBuilder cq = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title", "some text");
```

Then, I added it to the collate by calling its toString method:

```
String queryText = "the user query";
SuggestBuilder suggest = new SuggestBuilder()
                .setGlobalText(queryText)
                .addSuggestion("body",
                        SuggestBuilders
                        .phraseSuggestion("your.field")
                        .size(3)
                        .gramSize(3)
                        .addCandidateGenerator(new DirectCandidateGeneratorBuilder("your.field")
                                .suggestMode("missing"))
                        .collateQuery(cq.toString())
                        .collatePrune(true));
```

that toString() call seems to push the query through Elasticsearch's XContentBuilder, so you don't need to worry about backslash escaping and so on.